# Indian Citizen applying for UK visa from UAE

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, uae

I am Indian citizen currently working in UAE and mother of 2 children. I am planning to visit my sister in UK along with my kids. My husband is **not** traveling with me, i am applying Standard Visitor visa.

I have few queries around the online visa application form -

> 1) *Does anyone rely on you for financial support? Include both those travelling with you and those who are not.*

In general all my earnings goes to family savings and no contribution goes from my savings for any household expenses;  **should i select No even if my kids are traveling with me?**

> 2) Will you be travelling to the UK with someone who is not your partner, spouse, or dependant?

**From the above point if my kids are not dependent , do i need to give details of them here ?**

---

EDIT -
Kids are going to travel with me , I will be paying for the trip from my savings ; kids are 10 and 8 years

Comment: Sounds like you should answer No to (1) and Yes to (2). Are your children applying for visas at the same time as you? Are you paying the costs of the trip yourself for everyone? It might help you get better answers if you provide more background information, such as your childrens’ ages.

Comment: Are you saying that none of the money you earn supports your children in any way?! This seems a bit odd to me, and it may also seem odd to the entry clearance officer who processes your visa application.

Comment: my savings are mostly for the rainy day and few trips like this.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 If your bank statements show that none of your income is spent on day-to-day bills/living expenses etc for your children, you have no other dependents whom you support (eg parents), and your savings account(s) demonstrate that your earnings are used primarily for savings, then IMHO you can answer ‘No’ to this question.

Q2 IANAL but by inference if you don’t class your children as dependents and you’re travelling with them, then the answer to this question would be ‘Yes’.

Applicants’ individual circumstances differ and are personal to them. If you provide a coherent set of documents that supports the statements in your application, UKVI should be able to understand your situation. If you wish, you can explain in more detail in the ‘extra information’ section at the end of the application and/or in a cover letter.

If you’ve not done so already, it’s a good idea to check any UAE rules about one parent taking children abroad.